# Rendering components directly warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I've been getting the following warning for some time now and im rather uncertain as to what the problem actually is:

> Warning: render(): Rendering components directly into document.body is 
>   discouraged, since its children are often manipulated by third-party 
>   scripts and browser extensions. This may lead to subtle reconciliation 
>   issues. Try rendering into a container element created for your app.

Some people have suggested using `ReactDOM.render()` which is exactly what i was doing in the first place, i used facebook's Create React App to base my app on.

Any clues?

---

EDIT: My index.js

`ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));`

Comment: The warning should not happen unless you are rendering like this `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);`. Which version of react are you using ? I am not getting this warning.

Comment: So i just npm installed today and my package.json says `"react": "16.2.0"`

Comment: Are you able to render the start page given by create-react-app?

Comment: yes everything works fine that i know of, the app has moved on from boilerplate to almost final version, no real issues with it, just a very very annoying warning i see in my log all the time...

Comment: hmm..weird. The warning you are getting comes when you try to render directly within document.body. However, the code in your index.js is the correct fix for the warning you are getting. I have created a repo using create-react-app but I did not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: is there anything else that might be triggering it? maybe some other contributor added some jquery that does just that or something similar? im mainly lacking the imagination to see how i can figure out where this issue stems from.

P.S: The facebook sdk creates a <script> element directly on the page ( thats not inside the body tag though ). could this be it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This problem happens if in your `index.html` the html body tag has `root` id.

In your `index.html` change:

```
<body id="root"></body>
```

to:

```
<body>
   <div id="root"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: and what if you want use body in nwjs or electron app?!, actualy this give one branch deeper and affect the whole js engine for each operation. The only reason why react send this message is because browser use plugins, the better solution should be how desactivate this message

Answer (score 10):

Here are 2 possible solutions:

1. Modify your HTML and add a `<div>` and use that for rendering **(recommended)**:

```js
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React app</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

2. Create an element using JavaScript and append it to the body and use that to render:

```js
var reactapp = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(reactapp);
ReactDOM.render(<App />, reactapp);
```

Comment: You say recommended, by who? Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: For React 18 onwards you will need `createRoot` per [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html#updates-to-client-rendering-apis).